# Свой тип данных с границами в C++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно создать тип данных `Percent`, который бы хранил в себе только целые числа от 0 до 100, и чтобы логика была такая:

```c++
Percent a;
a = 101; // В a бы клалось не 101, а 100.
a = -5;  // В a клалось бы не -5, а 0.
```

И так далее.  Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Создавайте... А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Если бы я знал, как создать, я бы создал

Comment: Ну а в чем же затруднение? Делаете класс, перегружаете оператор присваивания и т.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На *C++* давно не писал, но видимо вам нужно что-то типа:

```c++
class Percent {
  uint8_t value;

public:
  const static int MAX_VALUE = 100;
  const static int MIN_VALUE = 0;

  Percent(int v) {
    if (v > MAX_VALUE) {
      this->value = MAX_VALUE;
    } else if (v < MIN_VALUE) {
      this->value = MIN_VALUE;
    } else {
      this->value = v;
    }
  }

  operator int() const { return this->value; }
};
```

```c++
Percent p = 128;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
// Output:
//   100

p = -5;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
// Output:
//   0
```

Comment: А оператор `=` нужен? Разве он сам не будет тип приводить?

Comment: @Qwertiy  Вы правы, убрал.

Comment: Можете ещё добавить оператор приведения к int, чтобы избавиться от `get_value`.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшой пример:

```
class Procent {
public:
    ...

    Procent& operator =(int v) {
        _v = v >= 100? 100: (v < 0? 0: v);
        return *this;
    } 

    ... 
private:
    int _v;
}
```

Остальное аналогично